What are the laws of workers
BH
Hi I know that there are certain laws of avadim (slaves) for example how a Jew should be merciful, etc, when having avadim, although now that slavery is highly not accepted around most areas of the world. What are the laws that apply to workers for example nowadays?
Are there areas where it talks about how a Jew should treat workers? For example what he should provide for them if they work for him? Or what to do if the person sells their time or hard labor to the other person?

Yes, there are many laws about how to treat workers.

There are indeed many laws about how a Jewish employer should treat employees. By way of an introduction to the topic, see this series of three articles entitled Decent Working Conditions by Rabbi Dr. Asher Meir:
Decent Working Conditions Part I: Equitable Treatment
https://outorah.org/p/19782
Decent Working Conditions Part II-Dignified Treatment
https://outorah.org/p/19783
Decent Working Conditions Part III - Generosity
https://outorah.org/p/19784

If you like my answer, please consider accepting it. Otherwise, please comment on how it can be improved.

The seventh chapter of Bava Metzia (in the Talmud) is called "One Who Hires Laborers", and is dedicated to this topic. Which in turn are codified by Rambam and the Shulchan Aruch in their respective codes, and addressed in numerous, numerous responsa throughout the millenia.
So yes, there are lots of laws about this. Too many to try and tackle in one question here.
